# How to use array_search for searching values from multiple values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array $DATA as below

```
{
    "LSP": "EXB",
    "AWB": "8421604",
    "SCANS": [
        {
            "SCAN_TIME": "2019-07-17 20:05:00",
            "SCAN_STATUS": "Uploaded",
            "SCAN_CODE": "001",
            "SCAN_LOCATION": "DLH"
        },
        {
            "SCAN_TIME": "2019-07-18 15:52:00",
            "SCAN_STATUS": "Picked Up",
            "SCAN_CODE": "0011",
            "SCAN_LOCATION": "DLH"
        },
        {
            "SCAN_TIME": "2019-07-19 00:22:00",
            "SCAN_STATUS": "Scanned",
            "SCAN_CODE": "003",
            "SCAN_LOCATION": "GAX"
        }

    ]
}
```

> $CODES = array("0011","003");

Now I want to search the **SCAN_CODE** values in **$CODES** from **$DATA**

So using **array_search** the same returns an error.
My current code to get KEY is

```
$SEARCH_KEY = array_search($CODES,array_column($DATA,"SCAN_CODE"));
```

**$SEARCH_KEY** returns

> **false**

My requirement is to get the ***first*** INDEX VALUE even if there are multiple INDEXES with same VALUE for SCAN_CODE and I guess **array_search** returns only the first instance.

Comment: if you take a close look, SCANS contains array of objects and to use the array_search function you need to convert it to array first

Comment: `$DATA` is not possible to use array_column on. Use it on `$DATA['SCANS']` adn it should work. And please post a working json.

Comment: @Andreas 
*Notice: Undefined index: SCANS*

*Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array*

*Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array*

Comment: yes that is because your json is invalid. post the real json

Comment: @Andreas also, array_search("003",array_column($DATA,"SCAN_CODE")); is working perfectly as it is string that is being searched. But it is not working with $CODES in place of "003"

Comment: @Alpha array_search is trying to find a `SCAN_CODE` value equal to the `$CODES` array, You have to search for each value in `$CODES` separately.

Comment: What are you expecting as output? The subarrays or just the indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `$DATA` is actually the JSON source, and that you've edited some of it out and left a dangling comma, then this code will find you the lowest index at which one of the values in `$CODES` appears. Note that you have to search for values individually, as [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) will otherwise look for the array as a value to match.

```
$DATA = json_decode($json, true);
$CODES = array("0011","003");
$SEARCH_KEY = count($DATA['SCANS']);
foreach ($CODES as $CODE) {
    $SEARCH_KEY = min($SEARCH_KEY, array_search($CODE,array_column($DATA['SCANS'],"SCAN_CODE")));
}
echo $SEARCH_KEY;
```

Output (for your data):

```
1
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mbfWZ)

If you want to find the scan with the earliest `SCAN_TIME` which matches one of the codes, you can sort the `SCANS` and then get an index into the sorted array e.g.

```
$DATA = json_decode($json, true);
$CODES = array("0011","003");
$SEARCH_KEY = count($DATA['SCANS']);
$SCANS = $DATA['SCANS'];
array_multisort(array_column($SCANS, 'SCAN_TIME'), $SCANS);
print_r($SCANS);
foreach ($CODES as $CODE) {
    $SEARCH_KEY = min($SEARCH_KEY, array_search($CODE,array_column($SCANS,"SCAN_CODE")));
}
print_r($SCANS[$SEARCH_KEY]);
```

Output (for my changed data in [this demo](https://3v4l.org/54MPf)):

```
Array
(
    [SCAN_TIME] => 2019-07-19 00:22:00
    [SCAN_STATUS] => Scanned
    [SCAN_CODE] => 003
    [SCAN_LOCATION] => GAX
)
```

Comment: Will it not work without **foreach** ?
Also, there is high possibility that there will be multiple instances under **SCANS**

So I need to find the first instance of my array_search() based on **SCAN_TIME** in ascending order with the values from $DATA['SCANS'].

Comment: @Alpha no, see my comment to your question. If the values in SCANS are in time order, this code will find the first one.

Comment: @Alpha see my edit. If the scans are not in time order, the new code will give you the value with the earliest times that matches a value in the `$CODES` array.

Answer (score 1):

`array_search` expects the parameter to be searched as string. You are passing an `array`.
You need to loop through `$CODES` and search for each code.

```
foreach( $CODES as $code ) {
    $SEARCH_KEY = array_search( $code , array_column($DATA['SCANS'],"SCAN_CODE"));
    if( $SEARCH_KEY !== false ) { //If we have find the Key, break from the loop.
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is the working [demo](https://3v4l.org/lYcAf)

Comment: I think this will return the last value, I want the first instance of any of the values from $CODES from $DATA['SCANS'] based on SCAN_TIME in ascending order

Comment: @Alpha Updated the answer to return first key. Previously it was getting all keys.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
$someJSON = '{
         "LSP": "EXB",
            "AWB": "8421604",
   "SCANS": [{"SCAN_TIME": "2019-07-17 20:05:00",
   "SCAN_STATUS": "Uploaded",
   "SCAN_CODE": "001",
   "SCAN_LOCATION": "DLH"
   },{
            "SCAN_TIME": "2019-07-18 15:52:00",
            "SCAN_STATUS": "Picked Up",
            "SCAN_CODE": "0011",
            "SCAN_LOCATION": "DLH"
        },
        {
            "SCAN_TIME": "2019-07-19 00:22:00",
            "SCAN_STATUS": "Scanned",
            "SCAN_CODE": "003",
            "SCAN_LOCATION": "GAX"
        }

    ]
}';

 $someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);
 $CODES = array("0011","003");
 $matched=array();
foreach($someArray['SCANS'] as $item)
{
   
 if (in_array($item['SCAN_CODE'], $CODES))
    {
    
    array_push($matched,$item['SCAN_CODE']);
   
    }
}
echo"<pre>";
print_r($matched);
exit;

?>
```